# How to get the last message by distinct userID using SQlite and iOS?

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, xcode5

I have a **"messages table"** , and i want only to retrieve the **"user ID"** with his last message.

I tried to add "2 sql statements" inside each other , But it keeps on looping without stopping,

```
   sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSMutableArray * messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_chatDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"SELECT DISTINCT FROMID , USERNAME from CHATCOMPLETE"];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_chatDB,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            int userID = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] integerValue];

            NSString *querySQL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                  @"SELECT MESSAGE , USERNAME from CHATCOMPLETE where FROMID=\"%d\"",userID];
            const char *query_stmt2 = [querySQL2 UTF8String];
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_chatDB,
                                   query_stmt2, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {

                    NSLog(@"LAST MESSAGE %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                               (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]);

                    sqlite3_reset(statement);

                }
            }
        }
                    sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
}
return messages;
```

**UPDATE:**
This is the insert message

```
    -(void)saveData:(NSString *)message toID:(int)toID fromID:(int)fromID isRead:(BOOL)read date:(NSDate *)date messageID:(int)messageID userName:(NSString*)userName
{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_chatDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CHATCOMPLETE (MESSAGE, TOID, FROMID, READ, date, MESSAGEID, USERNAME) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%d\", \"%d\", \"%c\", \"%@\", \"%d\", \"%@\")", message, toID, fromID, read, date,messageID,userName];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_chatDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"DONE");
          /*  status.text = @"Contact added";
            name.text = @"";
            address.text = @"";
            phone.text = @"";*/
        } else {
         //   status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_chatDB);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have a chatting table it has "ID as primary key ", fromID ,TOID,Message and i want to get the last message sent by fromID.

Comment: Any date/time columns?  If not, how can you find the "last message"?

Comment: just print NSLog(@"LAST MESSAGE %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                               (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]) in out side the while loop

Comment: always out side the loop show the last value only\

Comment: @trojanfoe can't i order them with messageID descending?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the problem is it doesn't get out of the while loop.

Comment: I don't know - as I mentioned in my first comment, anyone attempting to answer this question needs to know the schema of the tables involved rather than guessing it from your code.

Comment: MESSAGE, TOID, FROMID, READ, date, MESSAGEID, USERNAME@trojanfoe this what i select so far ,

Comment: Here's the full select statement of my Table"INSERT INTO CHATCOMPLETE (MESSAGE, TOID, FROMID, READ, date, MESSAGEID, USERNAME"

Comment: Please put it in your question and add the column types.  Better is the output from running `sqlite` from the command line and typing `.schema thetable;`.

Comment: @trojanfoe its my first time to deal with sqlite , so i dont know what you mean exactly by schema.

Comment: @Rob Thank you , I am not sure yet if this was the problem or not but i will change them

Comment: @user1286300 BTW, in your save routine, that will crash if the message, itself, has double quotes in it. Consider using `?` placeholders in your SQL and then use `sqlite3_bind_text` and `sqlite3_bind_int` to bind the values to the various placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. You have only one `sqlite3_stmt` variable for your two nested queries. You want a separate `sqlite3_stmt` for each.
2. You are calling `sqlite3_reset`. That is only used when binding new values to `?` placeholders in your prepared statement, which is not applicable here. Worse, you're calling it inside your loop.
3. Unrelated to the problem at hand, but for each prepared statement, don't forget to call `sqlite3_finalize` when done looping through the results, in order to release the memory used when preparing the statements.

---

Thus, you might want something like:

```
sqlite3_stmt *userStatement;
sqlite3_stmt *messageStatement;
int rc;                           // the return code
NSMutableArray * messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_chatDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *query_stmt = "SELECT DISTINCT FROMID , USERNAME from CHATCOMPLETE";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_chatDB, query_stmt, -1, &userStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: prepare userStatement failed: %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_chatDB));
    }
    else 
    {
        while ((rc = sqlite3_step(userStatement)) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            int userID = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] integerValue];

            const char *query_stmt2 = "SELECT MESSAGE , USERNAME from CHATCOMPLETE where FROMID=? ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"; // change the `ORDER BY` to use whatever field you want to sort by

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_chatDB, query_stmt2, -1, &messageStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"%s: prepare messageStatement failed: %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_chatDB));
            }
            else 
            {
                if (sqlite3_bind_int(messageStatement, 1, userID) != SQLITE_OK) 
                {
                    NSLog(@"%s: bind userID %d failed: %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, userID, sqlite3_errmsg(_chatDB));
                }

                while ((rc = sqlite3_step(messageStatement)) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    NSLog(@"LAST MESSAGE %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                               (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]);
                }
                if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%s: step messageStatement failed: %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_chatDB));
                }

                sqlite3_finalize(messageStatement);
            }
        }
        if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) 
        {
            NSLog(@"%s: step userStatement failed: %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_chatDB));
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(userStatement);
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%s: open %@ failed", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, _databasePath);
}
return messages;
```

Note, this code sample, in addition to my three points above, also:

1. Log errors using `sqlite3_errmsg` if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails.
2. Added check on return codes from `sqlite3_step`, too, again logging `sqlite3_errmsg` if it fails.
3. Added log if `sqlite3_open` failed.
4. Use `sqlite3_bind_int()` rather building SQL using `stringWithFormat`. In this case, because `userID` is numeric, this isn't critical, but if ever using string values in your `WHERE` clauses, using the `sqlite3_bind_text()` function becomes critical, so I just wanted to show the pattern.

   For example, look at your save routine and try saving a message that happens to have double quotation mark in it (e.g. `I spoke with Bob and he says "hello" to you.`). Your `stringWithFormat` construct will fail. If you use `sqlite3_bind_text`, it will solve that problem.

BTW, as you can see, when you add all of the proper validation of results, binding of values, etc., the code becomes a bit unwieldy. You might consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which greatly simplifies your SQLite Objective-C code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query to get the last message with a given `fromID`:

`SELECT * FROM chatting WHERE fromID=9999 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Didn't work ,This only returns the last message sent from all the users,But i want the last message for each userID

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, the following query will return the message with the largest date for each sender:

```
SELECT *, MAX(date)
FROM ChatComplete
GROUP BY FromID
```